# How safe is following code for creating mysql - yearly resetting field, safety also considering input from multiple requests

Tags: php, mysqli

I HAVE tables in this test code:

table WORKER -> name varchar(50)      , spec varchar(50) UNIQYE

table KEYGEN- > id INT AUTO_INCREMENT , year varchar(50)

spec should be like = 2009/54.

CODE: for checking and reseting (truncating) keygen table.

```
$insertedid=""; //to put last inserted id from keygen 
$spec="";   //spec number generated from year + $insertedid in table keygen
$year=date("Y");  //current year

$query="SELECT * from keygen WHERE year='{$year}' ";

    if($noviRed=$mysqli->query($query))
    {
        if($noviRed->num_rows==0)
        {
            $truncate="truncate keygen"; 
                if($mysqli->query($truncate)) {echo"<h2> TRUNCATING  TABLE OK </h2>";}  else { exit("fatal error");}

            $query2="INSERT INTO keygen(year) values('{$year}') ";
                if($mysqli->query($query2)) {$insertedid=$mysqli->insert_id;} else {exit("fatal error");}
        }
        else
        {

            $query2="INSERT INTO keygen(year) values('{$year}') ";
                if($mysqli->query($query2)) {$insertedid=$mysqli->insert_id;} else {exit("fatal error");}
        }
    }
    else {exit("fatal error");}
```

CODE: for inserting data into worker table.

```
$spec=$year."/".$insertedid; //generating spec number

if($insertedid!="" AND $spec!="")   
{
    $query3="INSERT INTO worker(name,spec) values('{$name}','{$spec}') ";   

    if($noviRed=$mysqli->query($query3)){echo"<h1>SUCCES </h1>";}
    else {exit("fatal error");}
}
```

Comment: the code isn't safe at all and is open to an sql injection. Use a prepared statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- which query is volunable? And how?

Comment: @Arnial Errrr... huh? - all of it lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Shown  code doesn't use any user input. `mysqli->insert_id` and `date("Y")` always ints. How is it possible to make SQL injection here?

Comment: Any time an unprepared variable is forced into a query there is an inherent danger @Arnial.

Comment: TOTALLY UNSAFE! And probably Off Topic

Comment: @RiggsFolly *"And probably Off Topic"* - 'tis ---^

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thanks, i will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely safe.

If multiple requests come in at once near the beginning of a year, the `TRUNCATE` query may end up running twice, as the `SELECT` will return zero rows for both requests. This would probably result in a unique key collision on one of the subsequent inserts.

Comment: Can this be avoided by using Prepared Statements ?

Comment: No. This is a completely separate issue from SQL injection.

Comment: what should i do to avoid truncate running twice?